# Play Video in Lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, ui

If I can get the download url of a video which is uploaded in my Salesforce org, is there a way to play the video in the lightning page or play on a pop up video player on click ? (Not using the static resource as it has size limitation)

Answer (score 3):

The only resources you're allowed to link to directly are "self" (including static resources), and *.visual.force.com (Visualforce pages). However, you can embed secure iframes that might include a media player. As an example, I went to youtube, copied a random link from my Recommended list, and embedded it directly into an application. Not all videos allow themselves to be embedded, but you could upload all of your videos to youtube as private videos (with URL sharing), so they would only be visible within your app or by someone with a direct link. I presume that other streaming video providers may also work as long as they support embedding.

Comment: Thanks.. but what I got is the content document download URL (something like this --><Mydomain>/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0688E0000008uIu?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER" ) which I don't think can be embedded. 
Uploading video to youtube as private sounds good but unfortunately its restricted as per the company policy.

Answer (score 3):

[Scorm Video's App](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpSjrEAF) on the App Exchange will play videos from numerous sources in VisualForce, Lightning, and Salesforce1. Clients can store content in any cloud provider and even store in Salesforce (storing video in Salesforce can be very costly).

Regardless of the source, content always plays natively via their player. The player enables you to play content hosted on other services like Vidyard, Wistia, YouTube and Vimeo natively in Salesforce with the same analytics of files hosted in cloud storage providers. Unlike Vidyard and Wistia, it is a federated player meaning that it can play content that is stored in multiple places, effectively turning Salesforce into an enterprise video platform. The player also supports PDFs in additions to most all video formats. Their player also works in communities. To the best of my knowledge, embedding is not required, but check out all the details in their listing on the app exchange to be certain.

Comment: To keep videos in Salesforce does not have to be so expensive via S-Drive tool which uses amazon s3 for storage.

Comment: @kirlisakal I don't see how using Amazon S3 to store videos is the same as storing videos on Salesforce nor do I see what it has to do with the question of how to view video content on a lightning page. S-Drive will allow you to create links from Amazon S3 storage on any page, but it won't have a dedicated player to help you display the linked content.

Comment: from version 1.28 it has a video player. Look at my answer below, there I explain how a video from different domain could play in salesforce vf page or lightning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML5 `<video>` tag and point the child `<source>` tag at a video URL (assuming it allows you to link directly to it)- or you can use `aura:unescapedHtml` to render the embed markup from a video provider site.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue with using video player html file in static resources. 
SFDC does not give permission to play videos from different url domain. So we need to call a player in iframe. We can store this video player inside static resources.

So, I have create a simple html5 video player html file. I save it to Static Resources of SFDC.

Then I call it from SFDC VF pages or lightning pages within Iframe. 
And I pass the video url inside the iframe url as parameters. It works well...

Here is codes: 
**videoPlayer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                overflow: hidden;
                margin:0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <video controls="" name="media" style="width: 100%;">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4" ></source> 
        </video>

        <script>
            var videoUrl = location.hash.replace(/#/, "");
            document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].setAttribute('src', videoUrl);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can embed iframe inside lightning page as below:

```
<iframe name="videoPlayer" class="video-player" src="{! $Resource.sources + '/VideoPlayer2/VideoPlayer.html#' + v.file.previewUrl}"
                                        allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

As you can see, iframe url takes video url as parameter after # char.

```
{! $Resource.sources + '/VideoPlayer2/VideoPlayer.html#' + v.file.previewUrl}
```

**$Resource.sources** is getting you static resource named sources path.

**'/VideoPlayer2/VideoPlayer.html#'** is my video player html file in static resource.

**v.file.previewUrl** is the url of video I want to play.

Finally, the url of Ifram will be something like that: 
    /resource/955412135546512/pf__sources/VideoPlayer2/VideoPlayer.html#https://www.abc.com/sample/video.mp4

Comment: Thanks.. But as  mentioned in the question, I am looking for a way without using the static resources.

Comment: You dont have to use static resources... it is just to store videoplayer.html you can upload html player any other server, than call it by an iframe, other steps are same.

Comment: @efirat Can you elaborate the src="{! $Resource.sources + '/VideoPlayer2/VideoPlayer.html#' + v.file.previewUrl}" part?

Comment: @Avinash I edited the answer, and tried to explain more about the url part.

Comment: @BijilRavindran by the way, I have shared this answer for other people who need to find a way using static resources. Could you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

For videos with their URL on a record you can use Salesforce CRM CMS, just include the video URL in your list View and detail pages.
You could also use native CMS for videos not connected to records to list or have individually as well